# ios 8.1 - controller with UIWebView not shown without WiFi connection

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Few days ago i started receiving user reports that my app is not working. After few hours of investigation i've found that controller is not shown (`[self.navigationController pushViewController:terminalController animated:YES];`) if it has `UIWebView` and there is no wifi connection! I did not believe it but i have 2 controllers - one with loading 'about the app' page and another is for showing some built-in app documentation. I'm testing on ios 8.1.2 and ipad 2.

Controller's `viewDidLoad` just is not invoked and the app just freezes. I've checked few times - if i turn wifi on and relaunch the app controllers are shown!

The problem is that i'm using uiwebview for showing local pages and it does not require wifi connection, so most users are very confused.

Any workaround?

Update: here is how i push controller:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    ASTerminalController *terminalController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ASTerminalController"];
    terminalController.htmlFilename = self.outputFilePath;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:terminalController animated:YES];
```

Update2: i've modified the app and now i'm creating `UIWebView` not in storyboard but in code. Now i can see `initWithFrame` hangs is there is no internet connection:

```
self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

**Update 1:** probably some 3rd-party code uses UIWebView and somehow blocks it (see semaphore is used):

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3aa34540 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x3aabf431 _os_semaphore_wait + 9
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x01b966f7 0x1b94000 + 9975
3   UIKit                           0x2ff893ef +[UIWebDocumentView initialize] + 39
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a4024d5 _class_initialize + 533
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a4022fd _class_initialize + 61
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a40805b lookUpImpOrForward + 251
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a407f53 _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 31
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a40e1d7 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 23
9   UIKit                           0x2fe743d1 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) containerIsBrowserView] + 73
10  UIKit                           0x2fe74353 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) textDocument] + 35
11  UIKit                           0x2fe74271 -[UITextSelectionView selection] + 41
12  UIKit                           0x2fe74e7f -[UITextSelectionView selectionChanged] + 167
13  UIKit                           0x304f17bb __47-[UITextInputController _setSelectedTextRange:]_block_invoke251 + 223
14  UIKit                           0x2fe74d8b __52-[UITextInputController _coordinateSelectionChange:]_block_invoke + 83
15  UIFoundation                    0x3756bb63 -[NSTextStorage coordinateReading:] + 35
16  UIKit                           0x2fe74d31 -[UITextInputController _coordinateSelectionChange:] + 97
17  UIKit                           0x304f14d3 -[UITextInputController _setSelectedTextRange:] + 599
18  UIKit                           0x2feda6db -[UITextView setAttributedText:] + 391
19  CppCode                         0x0011b925 0xd1000 + 305445
20  CppCode                         0x0011d0cb 0xd1000 + 311499
21  CppCode                         0x00119daf 0xd1000 + 298415
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2c931c5f __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 11
23  CoreFoundation                  0x2c88d6d1 _CFXNotificationPost + 1781
24  Foundation                      0x2d5bf125 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 69
25  Foundation                      0x2d5ebe33 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) registerDefaults:] + 71
26  WebKitLegacy                    0x389df8cd +[WebView initialize] + 301
27  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a4024d5 _class_initialize + 533
28  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a40805b lookUpImpOrForward + 251
29  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a407f53 _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 31
30  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a40e1d7 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 23
31  WebKitLegacy                    0x389df6cf WebKitInitialize + 67
32  UIKit                           0x3009cf97 ___UIApplicationLoadWebKit_block_invoke + 151
33  libdispatch.dylib               0x01b959c5 0x1b94000 + 6597
34  libdispatch.dylib               0x01b9662d 0x1b94000 + 9773
35  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a4024d5 _class_initialize + 533
36  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a40805b lookUpImpOrForward + 251
37  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a407f53 _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 31
38  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a40e1d7 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 23
39  CppCode                         0x0011182d 0xd1000 + 264237
40  UIKit                           0x2fe3a52b -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 599
41  UIKit                           0x2fe3a299 -[UIViewController view] + 21
42  UIKit                           0x2ffc3585 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 625
43  UIKit                           0x2fee34d3 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 419
44  UIKit                           0x2fee32d9 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 41
45  UIKit                           0x2fee326d -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 181
46  UIKit                           0x2fe37a6b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 511
47  QuartzCore                      0x2f85fa09 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 133
48  QuartzCore                      0x2f85b3e1 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 357
49  QuartzCore                      0x2f85b269 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 13
50  QuartzCore                      0x2f85ac4d CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 221
51  QuartzCore                      0x2f85aa51 CA::Transaction::commit() + 321
52  QuartzCore                      0x2f854929 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 53
53  CoreFoundation                  0x2c93fd93 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
54  CoreFoundation                  0x2c93d44f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 275
55  CoreFoundation                  0x2c93d857 __CFRunLoopRun + 911
56  CoreFoundation                  0x2c88b3bd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 473
57  CoreFoundation                  0x2c88b1cf CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
58  GraphicsServices                0x33c200a5 GSEventRunModal + 133
59  UIKit                           0x2fe997ad UIApplicationMain + 1437
60  CppCode                         0x0011f619 0xd1000 + 321049
61  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a981aad start + 1
```

Comment: Something else is wrong with your code - I can bring up a UIWebView fine even in airplane mode. Are you using Reachability on the main thread perhaps? I've seen apps do that and lock up when they try to determine if the network is available.

Comment: i did not believe it but i've checked it for few times. No 'viewDidLoad' is invoked after controller is pushed.